# OPENJSON SQL call to API with record pagination

Tags: json, sql-server, parsing, open-json

I'm trying to consume an API, parse the data and then put it in a table. I've done several tests and I can't have all the records because the API has pagination.I've seen other posts and I can't find the solution

```
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @json AS TABLE(Json_Table NVARCHAR(MAX))

-- Define the URL
SET @url = 'https://api.xpto.io/v1/catalog?X-API-KEY=ABCD123456&limit=10000&page=1'

-- This creates the new object.
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @token OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- This calls the necessary methods.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'

-- Grab the responseText property, and insert the JSON string into a table temporarily. This is very important, if you don't do this step you'll run into problems.
INSERT into @json (Json_Table) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'

-- Select the JSON string from the Table we just inserted it into. You'll also be able to see the entire string with this statement.
SELECT * FROM @json

-- Display all the data we just parsed, keep in mind you can negate certain columns we parsed. There is no requirement to display all the columns.
SELECT
    *
FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM @json))  -- USE OPENJSON to begin the parse.
```

This code returns all the data I can parse

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP8Tk.png)

If we parse the items it returns 10000 records.

```
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @json AS TABLE(Json_Table NVARCHAR(MAX))

-- Define the URL
SET @url = 'https://api.xpto.io/v1/catalog?X-API-KEY=ABCD123456&limit=10000&page=1'

-- This creates the new object.
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @token OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- This calls the necessary methods.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'

-- Grab the responseText property, and insert the JSON string into a table temporarily. This is very important, if you don't do this step you'll run into problems.
INSERT into @json (Json_Table) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'

-- Select the JSON string from the Table we just inserted it into. You'll also be able to see the entire string with this statement.
SELECT * FROM @json

-- Display all the data we just parsed, keep in mind you can negate certain columns we parsed. There is no requirement to display all the columns.
SELECT
    metadata.[id],
    metadata.[sku],
    metadata.[status],
    metadata.[highlight],
    metadata.[new],
    metadata.[stock],
    prices.[price_table]
    FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM @json))  -- USE OPENJSON to begin the parse.

-- At the highest level we n parts
WITH (
    [items] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS  Data

-- Parse the Metadata
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Data].[items])
WITH(
    [id] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [sku] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [status] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [highlight] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [new] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [stock] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [prices] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS metadata

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Metadata].[prices])
WITH(
    [price_table] NVARCHAR(MAX)
) AS prices
```

What I'm not able to do is add a paging loop so that it returns the 13494 records. Someone can help me?

Comment: This looks like T-SQL (and the image looks like SSMS), so why have you tagged [[tag:mysql]] here too?

Comment: sorry it was stackoverflow that suggested. ty RiggsFolly.

Comment: *"I'm trying to consume an API"* Then SQL Server is the *wrong* tool; use something else to consume the API and then pass the information from it to SQL Server. If you "must" do this in SQL Server, use CLR objects.

Comment: I understand @Larnu but I'm so close that I didn't want to give up :). I can even make two SP one with page=1 and another with page=2 but I wanted to have everything in the same SP. TY

Comment: I would gently suggest you are very *far* from completing this, as you are missing a whole load of error handling. `sp_OA` procedures are very difficult to use, and are basically deprecated. You could do this in about two lines of Powershell, don't misuse SQL Server for this. It's not a generalized scripting tool.

Comment: Do you want to just display the data, or do you need to store it in an SQL table?

Comment: I need store into SQL table

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you *not* use the `sp_OA` procedures, as they have many issues. T-SQL is not the place to do things like web access, it is not designed as a generalized scripting language.

Instead you can use something like Powershell, C# or Python to do this.

The algorithm is simple:

- Download the first page.
- Push it into an SQL query as a parameter. This will shred it using `OPENJSON` and store it in a table.
- The SQL will also return the URL of the next page, if any.
- If there is another page, loop back to the beginning.

So you need something like this, eg in Powershell:

```
$query = "
INSERT YourTable (id, sku, status, highlight, [new], stock, price_table)
SELECT
    metadata.id,
    metadata.sku,
    metadata.status,
    metadata.highlight,
    metadata.[new],
    metadata.stock,
    prices.price_table

FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.items')    -- use a Json path
WITH(
    id NVARCHAR(MAX),
    sku NVARCHAR(MAX),
    status NVARCHAR(MAX),
    highlight NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [new] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    stock NVARCHAR(MAX),
    prices NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS metadata

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Metadata].[prices])
WITH(
    price_table NVARCHAR(MAX)
) AS prices;

SET @nextUrl = JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.paging.next');
";

$url = "https://api.xpto.io/v1/catalog?X-API-KEY=ABCD123456&limit=10000&page=1";

while ($url -ne "") {
    try {
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url;
        $json = $response.Content;
    } finally {
        if ($response -ne $null) { $response.Dispose(); }
    }

    $jsonParam = New-DbaSqlParameter -ParameterName nextUrl -SqlDbType NVarChar -Size -1 -Value $json
    $output = New-DbaSqlParameter -ParameterName nextUrl -SqlDbType NVarChar -Size -1 -Direction Output;

    Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance YourServer -Database YourDB -CommandType StoredProcedure -Query $query -SqlParameter $output,$jsonParam;
    $url = [string]$output.Value;
}
```

> `Invoke-DbaQuery` is provided by the separate DBA-Tools module, which you can download.

> I suggest you rethink your data types: should `stock` be `nvarchar(max)` or rather `int` for example?